# How to assign order number in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Table: A

```
p_id | order | date
-----+-------+---------------
1    |  0    |   2014-01-12
1    |  1    |   2015-02-13
```

I want to assign the order in desc order based on the latest date.

For example, if I receive a record with same p_id on 2017-07-14, I would like to assign the order =2

How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: You should probably just be using an identity column rather than manually calculating this.

Comment: @underscore_d Why would an identity column make sense here?  They seem to be asking about inserting an incremental values based on the `p_id`.

Comment: @Siyual That's mildly easy to miss when the first sentence is simply _"I want to assign the order in desc order based on the latest date."_

Comment: Are you asking for an `INSERT` statement or an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: Shouldn't you just set the order id to auto increment? Or a calculated field for the order number? This seems like a poor approach.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to store order because your order criteria is date

```
SELECT p_id, date FROM A ORDER BY date
```

If you need a 0, 1, 2, etc then

```
SELECT 
    p_id, date, 
    order = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p_id ORDER BY date)
FROM A 
ORDER BY date
```

Otherwise, `order` could be an identity column to generate a number automatically

Comment: Might want to add a `PARTITION BY p_id` to the `OVER` clause, and `ROW_NUMBER()` defaults to `1`, not `0`.